# use with ajax passed data in my view - Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have some problems with using data I've passed with ajax. Thats the ajax snippet in my code:

```
$('a[data-id]').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            var domain = $(this).attr('data-domain');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'getdata',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {id: id, domain: domain, tld: tld},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.resultdomain').html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

In my Controller is just this:

```
public function getData(Request $req)
    {
        $getdomain = Domains::where('id', '=', $req['id'])->first();
        return $getdomain;
    }
```

So if I console.log(data) i'm getting an object with all the data I need. For example ( copy-paste from my console ) :

```
Object { id: "5", cus_id: "1", name: "hello-from-the-other-site", tld: ".com", ...... }
```

thats great but I want to use that also and I couldn't figure out how.

I want to print the domain-name + the tld. and some other things out.

something like:

Domain: ( here I want to be the name + the tld together ). 
Created-data : ( date ) 
Customer-ID = ( cus_id ).

Thanks for any help and sorry for my bad english :-)

---

current ajax code:

```
 $('a[data-id]').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            var domain = $(this).attr('data-domain');

            $.ajax({
                url: 'getdata',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {id: id, domain: domain, tld: tld},
                success: function (data) {
                    var domain = data.name + data.tld;
                    $('.resultdomain').html(domain);
                }
            });
        });
```

in my view:

`Domain: <div class="resultdomain"></div>`

Comment: try this in your controller return Response::json($getdomain);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` is an `object`. You can access the properties directly and create the strings you want to have. So in your like `success` callback you can do it like this:

```js
var data = {
    id: "5",
    cus_id: "1", 
    name: "hello-from-the-other-site", 
    tld: ".com"
};

var domain = data.name + data.tld;
$('.resultdomain').html(domain);
console.log("My Domain: " + domain);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resultdomain"></div>
```

Comment: I don't want to console.log() them. I want to print them out in my view. This just haven't worked. The place where the domain should be written is just empty.

Comment: Sorry, was thinking you know how to set it in your document. Its like `$('.resultdomain').html(domain);` @WellNo :)

Comment: look at my question, I've updated it how my ajax looks right now and how I'm trying to use it in my view. is there anything wrong with it? Cause it still don't work this way

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You could even do it directly if you only need it one time, like `$('.resultdomain').html(data.name + data.tld);`. @WellNo

Comment: but why domain is still empty? I'm getting just nothing printed out

Comment: Ahh, well, there could be an problem, because you try to use `var domain = ...` two times. Try to rename the variable in the `success` callback or do it this way: `$('.resultdomain').html(data.name + data.tld);`

Comment: thanks, yes that was the problem :) works fine now !

Answer (score 0):

In your JS code, the `success` function would need something like the following:

```
success: function (data) {
  $('.resultdomain').html(data.name + data.tld);
}
```